# load external libraries inside pyspark code

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark cluster I use in local mode. I want to read a csv with the databricks external library spark.csv. I start my app as follows:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/home/mebuddy/Programs/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6"

spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
sys.path.insert(0, spark_home + "/python")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'))

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext

try:
    sc
except NameError:
    print('initializing SparkContext...')
    sc=SparkContext()
sq = SQLContext(sc)
df = sq.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("/my/path/to/my/file.csv")
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.csv.
```

My question: how can I load the databricks.spark.csv library INSIDE my python code. I don't want to load it from outside (using --packages) from instance.

I tried to add the following lines but it did not work:

```
os.environ["SPARK_CLASSPATH"] = '/home/mebuddy/Programs/spark_lib/spark-csv_2.11-1.3.0.jar'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create `SparkContext` from scratch you can for example set `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` **before** `SparkContext` is intialized:

```
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = (
  "--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0 pyspark-shell"
)

sc = SparkContext()
```

If for some reason you expect that `SparkContext` has been already initialized, as it is suggested by your code, this won't work. In local mode you could try to use Py4J gateway and `URLClassLoader` but it doesn't look like a good idea and won't work in a cluster mode.

Comment: How to specify multiple packages? I tried adding another package by using a comma separator, it shows an error.