# Adding Spark packages in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have set up my PyCharm to link with my local spark installation as per [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext, SparkConf
from operator import add
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")
conf.setAppName("Test")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(2012, 8, "Batman", 9.8), (2012, 8, "Hero", 8.7), (2012, 7, "Robot", 5.5), (2011, 7, "Git", 2.0)],["year", "month", "title", "rating"])
df.write.mode('overwrite').format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("file:///Users/abhattac/PycharmProjects/WordCount/users")
```

This requires Databrick's avro jar to be shipped to worker node. I can get it done using spark-submit from shell like the following:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/bin/pyspark AvroFile.py --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1
```

I couldn't find out how to provide --packages option when I am running it from inside PyCharm IDE. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` environment variable, either by passing it using environment variables section of the PyCharm run configuration (the same place where you set `SPARK_HOME`)

[image]

or using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.environ) directly in your code as shown in [load external libraries inside pyspark code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35346567/1560062)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the following: os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1' That didn't work and kept giving java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.avro Then I included these two lines in spark-defaults.conf spark.driver.extraClassPath     /Users/abhattac/PycharmProjects/WordCount/spark-avro_2.10-2.0.1.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath   /Users/abhattac/PycharmProjects/WordCount/spark-avro_2.10-2.0.1.jar With those lines I could make it work.

Comment: The original stackoverflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464845/automatically-including-jars-to-pyspark-classpath

Comment: Missing `pyspark-shell`?

Comment: @user3138594 - In windows, how to specify the path? if i need to add multiple jar's, then how to add them?