# Spark-Avro Error in PYCHARM [TypeError: 'RecordSchema' object is not iterable]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, avro

I am trying to run a simple spark program to read an avro file in **PYCHARM** environment. I keep getting this error which i am not able to resolve. I appreciate your help.

```
from environment_variables import *
import avro.schema
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

Schema = avro.schema.parse(open(SCHEMA_PATH, "rb").read())
print(Schema)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("indu").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("avro").load(list(Schema))
print(df)
```

The schema printed looks like this

```
{"type": "record", "name": "DefaultEventRecord", "namespace": "io.divolte.record", "fields": [{"type": "boolean", "name": "detectedDuplicate"}, {"type": "boolean", "name": "detectedCorruption"}, {"type": "boolean", "name": "firstInSession"}, {"type": "long", "name": "clientTimestamp"}, {"type": "long", "name": "timestamp"}, {"type": "string", "name": "remoteHost"}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "referer", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "location", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "int"], "name": "devicePixelRatio", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "int"], "name": "viewportPixelWidth", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "int"], "name": "viewportPixelHeight", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "int"], "name": "screenPixelWidth", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "int"], "name": "screenPixelHeight", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "partyId", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "sessionId", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "pageViewId", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "eventId", "default": null}, {"type": "string", "name": "eventType", "default": "unknown"}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentString", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentName", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentFamily", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentVendor", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentType", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentVersion", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentDeviceCategory", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentOsFamily", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentOsVersion", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "userAgentOsVendor", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "int"], "name": "cityIdField", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "cityNameField", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "countryCodeField", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "int"], "name": "countryIdField", "default": null}, {"type": ["null", "string"], "name": "countryNameField", "default": null}]}
```

**The error got is,**

```
21/03/02 16:06:50 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Git_repo\Project_Red\spark_streaming\spark_scripting.py", line 15, in <module>
    df = spark.read.format("avro").load(list(jsonFormatSchema))
TypeError: 'RecordSchema' object is not iterable
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be 3 corrections in your code:

1. You don't have to separately load a schema file because any Avro data file already contains it in its header.
2. The `load()` method in your `spark.read.format("avro").load(list(Schema))` expects a path to your Avro file, not a schema.
3. `print(df)` won't give any meaningful output. Just use `df.show()` if you want to glance at the data in your Avro file.

Having said that, you may have already got an idea of what must be changed in your code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("indu").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("avro").load(DATA_PATH)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Hi, This doesn't solve the problem... I have reposted the error here, kindly check this please.       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66452376/spark-avro-error-in-pycharm-pyspark-sql-utils-analysisexception

Comment: It does solve the problem. What you reported in that other question is another problem, a problem with your environment (missing spark-avro)

Comment: Hi Egordoe, Thanks. But still, i am not able to resolve the "missing spark-avro" error. Could you suggest me what to do please to get rid of this error?

Comment: You must set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS as proposed here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046758/adding-spark-packages-in-pycharm-ide